# IsolatedStorageException exception even if it has passed File.Exists Test

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mono

i have developed a simple android game in unity3d, i want to read a file which is created by myself. it is a simple config file.
   exception call stack:

> IsolatedStorageException: Could not find a part of the path "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Test.Demo/files/basic.cfg".
>
> 07-16 12:04:35.905  4248  5019 I Unity   :
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in :0
>
> 07-16 12:04:35.905  4248  5019 I Unity   :   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [0x00000] in :0
>
> 07-16 12:04:35.905  4248  5019 I Unity   :   at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in :0
>
> 07-16 12:04:35.905  4248  5019 I Unity   :   at System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes (System.String path) [0x00000] in :0
>
> 07-16 12:04:35.905  4248  5019 I Unity   :   at FileManager.ReadFile (System.String filePath) [0x00000] in :0**

this is my read file code.

```
public static byte[] ReadFile(string filePath)
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
}
```

Here is the exception message I recieve:

> IsolatedStorageException: Could not find a part of the path "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Test.Demo/files/basic.cfg".

I don't understand that why the `ReadAllBytes` method throws this exception, even when the `File.Exists()` test passes.

This is the code I find in unity.mono:

```
    public static FileStream OpenRead (string path)
    {
        return new FileStream (path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    }

    //
    // The documentation for this method is most likely wrong, it
    // talks about doing a "binary read", but the remarks say
    // that this "detects the encoding".
    //
    // This can not detect and do anything useful with the encoding
    // since the result is a byte [] not a char [].
    //
    public static byte [] ReadAllBytes (string path)
    {
        using (FileStream s = OpenRead (path)) {
            long size = s.Length;
            // limited to 2GB according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx
            if (size > Int32.MaxValue)
                throw new IOException ("Reading more than 2GB with this call is not supported");

            int pos = 0;
            int count = (int) size;
            byte [] result = new byte [size];
            while (count > 0) {
                int n = s.Read (result, pos, count);
                if (n == 0)
                    throw new IOException ("Unexpected end of stream");
                pos += n;
                count -= n;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

This is my manifest.xml permission configuration:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is not all of them though.

This exception is not throw every time, but sometimes I receive this exception too.

Comment: Did you add permission to manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: yes,i have add this:

Comment: One more question: are you sure that you package is com.Test.Demo and you have folder with this name inside Android folder on sdcard? If it is, than you need to check unity support, cause IsolatedStorageException it is not android exception, but unity